# I'm planning to develop an OAuth server in a monolith, can we use light-oauth2 as libraries in our app instead of microservices?

Tags: light-4j

If I were to develop an OAuth server in an existing monolith and don't want to move away from the monolith due to operational issues, can I use the light-oauth as a library instead of individual services ? Is it recommended to do so ? If not, does anyone know a library which lets me do that ?

I've tried researching about this and all I found was repos which creates a new service which acts as an OAuth server instead of a library which gives the utility to make it as an OAuth service.